# Run two functions side by side with access to the same class instance?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-telegram-bot

I'm trying to run two functions side by side.

Basically, I have a part of my code which sets and variable (in a class) to False which in turn, should disable a function from executing.

However, it can be set back to True again and a process then executes at a given time. So I need a way of checking that variables state constantly.

I have put it in a separate function and then calling it alongside my main function. I have found that if I put them together. the while True blocks the rest of the function from executing.

telegram_bot.py

```
from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler, MessageHandler, Filters
import logging
import os
from alarm import Alarm
import time

alarmpi = Alarm()

def alarmenable(bot, update):
    if alarmpi.alarm_enabled:
        update.message.reply_text("Alarm is already enabled")
    else:
        update.message.reply_text("Alarm has been enabled")
        alarmpi.alarm_enabled = True

def alarmdisable(bot, update):
    if alarmpi.alarm_enabled:
        alarmpi.alarm_enabled = False
        #alarmpi.alarm_enabled = False
        update.message.reply_text("Alarm has been disabled")
    else:
        update.message.reply_text("Alarm is already disabled")
        print('From sub :' + str(Alarm.alarm_enabled))

def main():

    <code to start the bot and then go into 'idle mode'.. always listening for commamnds>

def timer():
    while True:
        if alarmpi.alarm_enabled:
            print('We are live!')
        else:
            print('Hibernating'_

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
    timer()
```

alarm.py

```
class Alarm:

def __init__(self):
    self.alarmpi = None
    self.alarm_playing = False
    self.alarm_time = '16:10'
    self.alarm_enabled = True

def alarm_toggle(self, status):
    self.alarm_enabled = status
    return self.alarm_enabled
```

I've tried running both functions in my telegram_bot file with the Threading and Multiprocess modules. But the functions don't share the same class instance.

Answer (score 0):

Worked it out.. moved the while loop into my class and called it in the main() function.